# How to create simple GUI in Nuklear with minimum amount of code?

Tags: java, maven, user-interface, nuklear

I need to create simple GUI using Nuklear and Java. I just need a couple of buttons and radio buttons. When I click on them, on the screen should appear short text. Unfortunately I found nothing about that on the Web.
It wouldn't be anything hard to do if I could using Swing or something like that, but Nuklear is necessary :/
Could anybody help me with that and explain/show example of one button in window?
Regards :)